# How to test web apps on multiple browsers with Coded UI Test (CUIT)?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, automation, coded-ui-tests

I wonder how to test web apps on multiple version of browsers with coded UI tests? Such as IE 7-9, Firefox 9-11, and latest Chrome.

My first thought was that I'll install those browsers on my development box or build server. But that really doesn't sound right even if it's technically possible.

I probably need some pointers on how to approach testing web apps on multiple browsers and multiple versions.

Visual Studio 2010
TFS 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, First see the Coded UI supported platforms as the following,

[image]

Second, for creating matrix test for the supported platforms, just see the following post,

[Configuration matrix testing using Visual Studio Lab Management](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lab_management/archive/2011/05/26/configuration-matrix-testing-using-visual-studio-lab-management.aspx)